# Standard practice when merging papers on arxiv

Tags: publications, collaboration, arxiv

I and another author have decided to merge our manuscripts into one paper.
Both of us have already put preprints on [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/). How should we handle the merging on arxiv? Is there a standard practice?

I can think of three options:

1. Create a new submission for the merged paper.

   Upload the merged paper as a revision of both of the original preprints.

   [Withdraw](https://arxiv.org/help/withdraw) one of the original preprints and upload the merged paper as a revision to the other.

I worry that option 1 might look like we are spamming arxiv by uploading three papers when we really should only have uploaded one. Option 2 is undesirable because then there are two versions of the exact same paper on arxiv. Option 3 is asymmetric.

Has anyone had a similar experience?

Comment: I think I've seen both 1 and 3, never 2.  Whether asymmetry for 3 concern depends on the relationship between the manuscripts (e.g., if one is a sequel to the other, this "asymmetry" is fine).  What you want to avoid with 3 is having people miss some of your results because they've only looked at one of your preprints but not the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 should be fine **if you add appropriate comments** and withdraw old papers.

Here is how we did it recently:

- http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04963 (merger)
- http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2109 (withdrawn)
- http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2667 (withdrawn)

In the merged paper, it is important to add a comment; otherwise you will probably trigger https://arxiv.org/help/overlap